# FCM Push Notification Not Triggering When my App is in Foreground: iOS - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated the Firebase Push Notification..

I received the push notification from my server when my app is in
background and when i tap on that `didReceiveRemoteNotification` methods
gets called, But when my app is in foreground(i.e. active) then
`didReceiveRemoteNotification` method is not triggering..

My notification payload from server:

> ```
>   "data":{  
>       "message":"mymsg",
>    },
>    "notification":{  
>       "title":"mytitle",
>       "body":"mybody",
>       "sound": default,
>       "priority": high
>    },
>    "to":"token"
> }
> ```

Do I need to add any extra key in notification payload or should I do somenthing in my project target?

Comment: You'll want to set the priority of the notification. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899712/fcm-background-notifications-not-working-in-ios and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450595/firebase-cloud-messaging-ios-no-background-push-notification

Comment: Added but still same issue..!

Comment: Watch carefully where you put the `priority` property, because in your updated payload you've put it in the wrong location.

Comment: then where should i put that...?